# Formatting does not automatically update when using excel with win32com

Tags: python, excel, number-formatting, win32com

I am trying to generate a report in excel using win32com. I can get the information into the correct cells. However, one of my columns contains an ID number, and excel is formatting it as a number (displaying it in scientific notation). I have tried formatting the cell as text using `sheet.Range(cell).NumberFormat = '@'`, which works, but will only update after the cell has been selected in the actual excel file. The same thing happens whether I format the cell before or after entering the data. Is there a way to refresh the cell formatting using win32com? I want the ID numbers to display correctly as soon as the com instance is made visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a single leading quote to Excel ahead of the number, for example `"'5307245040001"` instead of `"5307245040001"`